# What's the main purpose of React Native? Is it necessary to learn React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Can you please explain what's the main purpose of React Native? Is it necessary to learn React Native after learning the main React.js?

Comment: Does [this](https://www.netguru.com/glossary/react-native) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

[React Native](https://reactnative.dev/) is framework for creating native apps for Android and iOS using React. If you are not going to develop mobile apps, you don't have to learn React Native.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest advantage of React Native is that developers don't need to create separate codes for different platforms (Android and iOS). and Hot reloading & Large community support & More plugins.
Developed by Facebook.

Comment: That sounds great!

Answer (score 0):

From your question , the main purpose of **React Native** is creating native applications for mobile(both **android and ios**) .If you are trying to develop mobile application I would suggest learning **'React Native'** than ***'Flutter'.*** Based on the customer's requirement we can build any kind of apps .

[Refer here for more details](https://reactnative.dev/docs/getting-started)